# Pass structures from the parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that acquires and process data, I want to start a new activity that would be able to access a few variables (complex data structures) from the parent activity.

I can't use using serialization here, is there a simple way to pass a variable between activities? Or maybe access one of the functions of the parent activity and get the variable I need?

Comment: what is the reason serialization cannot be used here?

Comment: see android guide 'How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?' http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of Bundle Class for this.

In the first activity(firstactivity.java) :

```
//Create the intent
  Intent i = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
  EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
  String UserName=txtUserName.getText().toString();

  //Create the bundle
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  //Add your data to bundle
  bundle.putString(“UserName”, UserName);  
  //Add the bundle to the intent
  i.putExtras(bundle);

  //Fire that second activity
   startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity (secondactivity.java):

```
//Get the bundle
Bundle objBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//Extract the data
String UserName= objBundle.getString(“UserName”);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to pass a variable between activities?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("isLogin", "yes");
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity to get value.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
   String value = extras.getString("isLogin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receivers to pass data between activities, create singleton on main activity or use static getters / setters to acquire variables.

Still I think that there is something wrong with your design if you want to pass variables that aren't serializable.